# How can I open an existing form in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm making a video editor and I want the program to open a new window when creating a file. So I created a new form and I wrote something like this:
`Form fm = create_file(); fm.Show();`

And I got an error, which said that create_file cannot be used as a method. I tried deleting the brackets, and it said that it's incorrect in the current context. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `create_file `? We have no idea what it is.

Comment: Is `create_file` the name of the form, then you need `Form fm = new create_file();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should write:

```
Form fm = new create_file();
```

then:

```
fm.Show();
```

Do not forget to write **new** when you create an Object from the Form fm!

Comment: Should be in a `using` block also, or otherwise disposed

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form FormIsOpen(string name)
{
        FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form form in forms)
            if (form.Name.Equals(name))
                return form;

        return null;
 }

 public void OpenForm(Form instance, string name)
 {
        Form form = FormIsOpen(name);
        if (form == null)
            instance.Show();
        else
        {
            instance.Dispose();

            form.Show();
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            form.Activate();
        }
  }
```

You can call by using below code

```
OpenForm(new MyForm(), nameof(MyForm));
```